# Как отследить изменения доступа к разрешениям приложения?

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

В связи с тем, что с 1 ноября 2018 года обязали во всех опубликованных в Google Play Market приложениях установить "targetSdkVersion=26", раработчики стали всё чаще обращаться к теме обработки всех разрешений приложения.

Вот и у меня появился очередной вопрос:
Приложение не может в принципе работать без разрешений (пермишенов), которые указаны в моем приложении, поэтому в начале приложения сделал блок, который заставляет пользователя разрешить ВСЕ пермишены и пока он ВСЕ разрешения не откроет, приложение предлагает разрешить ВСЕ пермишены или закончить работу (выйти).
Этот блок работает как часы, претензий нет!

Но, как отследить, если пользователь во время работы приложения запретит одно из пермишенов вручную через настройки приложения и мне надо сразу же закончить работу приложения (например команду finish();) предварительно кинув тост (может быть какой-то слушатель есть для всего этого) или иным способом закрыть приложение?!

Подскажите, кто в теме!

Comment: Перед применением метода, нужно еще раз проверить нужные разрешения. Не понимаю, зачем обязывать пользователя при запуске выдавать все разрешения?

Comment: Andrey Mihalev, таких различных методов сотни в тексте! Обязывать заставил заказчик. Извините, но стандартными методами обработки пермишенов он не хочет пользоваться по некоторым причинам, которые не относятся к теме вопроса.

Comment: Не хочет пользоваться стандартными, пишите свои. Но проверять все равно придется. Хоть сотни, хоть тысячи. Ну или эксепшн какой ловить.

Comment: Ходят слухи, что при изменении разрешений процесс приложения прибивается: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958485. Если это так, то дальше приложение не разворачивается, а запускается заново и тут должны сработать Ваши "часы" (хотя не знаю как там с back stack и instance state, возможно придётся вызывать проверку в `onCreate` каждой активности).

Comment: Глянь библиотеку https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions , через нее можно получать разрешения, переходить в окно разрешений приложения и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите данную библиотеку [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher)

Тут есть аннотация `@OnPermissionDenied` с помощь которой вы можете пометить что делать, когда нету пермишна и разные другие аннотации есть. Очень удобная библиотека